# TYPO3 - Sidebar navigation li has no 'active' class when on page (active/current)

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

TYPO3 - Sidebar navigation li has no 'active' class when on page (active/current). I have this sidebar navigation ... but the li has no active added when on a specifc page. Does anybody see what's wrong?

```
lib.navigation = COA
lib.navigation {
  20 = HMENU
  20 {
    entryLevel = 1
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
    expAll = 1
    #collapse = active 
    wrap = <ul class="sidebar-nav" id="menu">|</ul>
    NO {
        subst_elementUid = 1
        ATagBeforeWrap = 1
        allStdWrap.insertData = 1
        wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
        }
    ACT <.NO
    ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
    CUR <.ACT
    #CUR <.NO
    #CUR = 1
    CUR.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
    #CUR.linkWrap = <strong>|</strong>
    ... 
    }
    .... 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding ACT = 1. Unlike NO, ACT and CUR are not active by default.

See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/MenuObjects/CommonItemStates/Index.html for more information about this.

Comment: or add a `NO = 1` to the `NO` before you copy it to the `ACT`, `CUR`, ....